# How to evaluate this integral ?

Tags: improper-integrals, laplace-transform

$$ I(\alpha)=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\arctan(x)}{e^{\alpha x}} \,dx     $$  for all alpha>=0

I tried to do it with Laplace transform , but having trouble with finding LT of arctan(x), any other suggestions ?

Comment: I would start by integrating by parts, to get $1/(x^2+1)$ instead of $\arctan x$.

Comment: sorry but i'm not introduced to residue theorem , can you show me your approach sir ?

Comment: Anyway, [according to WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(-x)arctan+x+dx) there is no closed form for $\alpha=1$

Comment: okay then if i try to apply some numerical methods what can i do with alpha ? @Crostul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. We assume $\alpha>0$. By an integration by parts (as proved by @the_candyman), one has
$$
I(\alpha) = \left[\frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{-\alpha}\cdot\arctan x\right]_0^\infty+\frac{1}{\alpha} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{1+x^2}\:dx=0+\frac{1}{\alpha} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{1+x^2}\:dx
$$ then one deduces
$$
\begin{align}
I(\alpha) &=\frac{i}{2\alpha}  \int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{x+i}-\frac{1}{x-i}\right)e^{-\alpha x}dx
\\\\I(\alpha)&=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\cdot\text{Im}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x+i}\:dx
\end{align}
$$giving

> $$
> \begin{align}
> I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha x}\arctan(x)\,dx  &=\frac{\sin \alpha}{\alpha}\cdot \text{Ci}(\alpha)+\frac{\cos \alpha}{\alpha}\cdot \text{si}(\alpha), \qquad \alpha>0,
> \end{align}
> $$

where we have used the special functions [$\text{Ci}$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html) and [$\text{si}$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) given by
$$
\text{Ci}(z)=- \int_{z}^{\infty}\frac{\cos t}{t}\:dt,\quad\text{Re}\:z>0, \qquad \text{si}(z)=-\int_{z}^{\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t}\:dt, \quad z \in \mathbb{C}.
$$

Comment: $$\mathrm{si}(z) = \mathrm{Si}(z) -\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Yes, it's an equivalent form.

Comment: A more generalized form appears in Lewin's book 

$$\int^\infty_0 e^{-\alpha x}\mathrm{Li}_2(-x^2) \,dx= \frac{-2}{\alpha}\left[\mathrm{Ci}^2(\alpha)+\mathrm{si}^2(\alpha) \right]$$

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai is the pdf of the book available ?

Comment: @OlivierOloa the special function that you used for the integral can i get a derivation of it somewhere ? any resources ?

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light Thanks. Have you clicked on the two hyperlinks in my answer?

Comment: ohh sorry i missed it thanks :)

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light, send me an email and I will forward it to you. You can find my email in my profile.

Comment: okay thanks i'll send you

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Nice observation, Lewin's book is a treasure.

Comment: @OlivierOloa, I've never seen a similar book. The number of identities proved in that book blows my mind. One of a kind really.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your integral as follows:
$$I(\alpha)=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\arctan(x)e^{-\alpha x} \,dx.$$

Recall that you can use the [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts): $$\int f(x)g'(x)dx = f(x)g(x) - \int f'(x) g(x) dx.$$

Using this fact, you can pose:

$$\begin{cases}
f(x) = \arctan(x)\\
g'(x) = e^{-\alpha x}
\end{cases} \Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
f'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}\\
g(x) = -\frac{1}{\alpha}e^{-\alpha x}
\end{cases}.$$

Then:

$$I(\alpha) = \left[-\frac{1}{\alpha}\arctan(x)e^{-\alpha x}\right]_{x=0}^{x=+\infty} - \int_0^{+\infty} -\frac{1}{\alpha}e^{-\alpha x}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx .$$

Can you go on from this point?

Comment: yeah after @crostul told to use by parts i did the that but still having trouble with the second integral

Comment: Good start (+1)